# Htaccess fail to redirect to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Im trying to have a htacess file within my root folder so i can redirect the user to index.php file, if for example trying to access any file inside my  root directory. I failed to do that. I have that file inside my root folder as i should, but when im trying to access files typing the names in the URL, i actually have access to the files. So the .htaccess file does not work.
I have to mention that im trying to do that locally, having wamp installed and using slim framework. I do not know if something mess with these.

The code that i have in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have that file inside my root folder as i should, but when im trying to access files typing the names in the URL, i actually have access to the files

That means you want even the existing files not to be shown, and all requests should be redirected to index.php.

If that is the case then why do you have these conditions? Remove these

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Those 2 conditions mean apply that redirect only if the requested url is niether a file nor a directory. No wonder for files that are actually present your redirect is not working. You told it so.

Comment: Oh thank you so much Hanky!!! you were right i didnt know that actually i was telling to show the contents. i did what you said, i removed the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f , but not it doens't redirect to the index.php. i just have an 404 error!